# Most efficient way to find subdirectories paths

Tags: python, algorithm, directory, glob, os.path

Let's say I've got the following directory structure

```
PROJECT
|
+ BUILD
|    |
|    + STH1
|    |    |
|    |    + 6.11.2
|    |    |
|    |    + 6.11.3
|    |    |
|    |    + .....
|    + STH2
|    |    |
|    |    + 6.11.2
|    |    |
|    |    + 6.11.3
|    |    |
|    |    + .....
+ COMMON
|    |
|    + 6.11.2
|    |
|    + ....
```

What would be the most efficient way to find all the 6.11.2 directories in the PROJECT directory in python?

I tried using

```
glob.glob('PROJECT/**/6.11.2', recursive=True)
```

It works, but it's not the best solution for me, because it will also look for directories like

```
PROJECT/BUILD/STH1/6.11.2/6.11.2
```

So it takes a lot of time, I only need to find the 1st occurrence of the directory 6.11.2, so searching deeper into it is a waste of time (also situation like sth/6.11.2/6.11.2 will not happen in my structure)

Is there a better way to do the search in python?

Note that 6.11.2 is also quite complex directory with lots of files and subdirectories, that's why it takes a lot of time to do the search recursively.

Comment: Is necesary use glob.? ....I use os.walk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you don't want to find directories with the same [basename](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename), is that so? If yes, then this should do the trick:

```py
import os
from collections import deque
from typing import List, Set


def scandir_only_dirs(path: str) -> List[str]:
    return [f.path for f in os.scandir(path) if f.is_dir()]


def scandir_no_same_basename(path: str) -> Set[str]:
    result = set()
    queue = deque(scandir_only_dirs(path))

    if not queue:
        return result

    visited_basenames = set()

    while queue:
        currdir = queue.popleft()
        basename = os.path.basename(currdir)
        if basename not in visited_basenames:
            result.add(currdir)
            queue.extendleft(scandir_only_dirs(currdir))
            visited_basenames.add(basename)

    return result
```

With your example directory tree, this function returns:

```py
{'.\\build',
 '.\\build\\sth1',
 '.\\build\\sth2',
 '.\\build\\sth2\\6.11.2',
 '.\\build\\sth2\\6.11.3',
 '.\\common'}
```

This algorithm can of course be modified depending on whether you want some other part other than the `basename` to be taken into consideration, but the general idea is to perform a [traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and establish what is your criteria for "visited".

**Edit**

Adding the answer below because I had misunderstood the question:

```py
def find_paths_to_dir(dir_basename: str, from_path: str=".") -> Set[str]:
    result = set()
    queue = deque(scandir_only_dirs(from_path))

    if not queue:
        return result

    while queue:
        currdir = queue.popleft()
        basename = os.path.basename(currdir)
        if basename == dir_basename:
            result.add(currdir)
        else:
            queue.extendleft(scandir_only_dirs(currdir))

    return result
```

Comment: Not really, what i want to find are paths to 6.11.2 directories inside the PROJECT directory, and if I find one ex. `PROJECT/COMMON/6.11.2` I do not have to go deeper into it, that would mean after finding it, I can completly skip searching the rest of the COMMON directory

Comment: @TomaszHołda in this case it's even simpler: I edited the answer with that. The idea is the same: traversal, but this time add to the result set when you find what you want and add to the queue when you don't.

Answer (score 0):

The slowness is likely due to matching against files more than nested `6.11.2` directories. See if appending `/` to your pattern helps to possibly ignore files.

Also, try using the iterator version [iglob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) which will save the cost of `glob` putting everything in a list.

```
filter(lambda p: p.count('6.11.2') == 1, glob.iglob('PROJECT/**/6.11.2/', recursive=True))
```

Otherwise you could always write your own directory traversal with [os.scandir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir).